# What does Photoshop's "High Pass" filter actually do under the hood?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, mathematics

I'm trying to wrap my head around this filter. Like some other filters, I find that I don't understand how it works, both visually and in terms of the algorithm. I'm hoping that by learning the latter, the former would also somehow click in.

Comment: Consider asking what custom is for next ;)

Comment: If you want to understand the algorithm, I suggest [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to
Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/ch7/1.htm).

Comment: Check this case: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/98558/high-pass-photoshop-filters-skips-the-edges-of-the-histogram There's an answer which shows in details 1) how Photoshop's HP filtering works internally 2) the assumed working principle creates the same as the HP filter. The story  isn't based on disassemblig Photoshop. It contains one assumption: Photoshop's HP filtering is done by subtracting from the image a blurred version of the same image.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**High pass is the opposite of gaussian blur**

If you take an image and blur it you only keep the "low frequencies". High pass makes the opposite, it only lets the "high frequencies" pass, or what most people call "the details". Any image can be deconstructed into these two components.

[image: deconstructed image]

Have you used unsharp mask to sharpen an image? That filter is actually equivalent to taking an image and adding a high pass filtered copy to it. You can confirm this in Photoshop by applying the high pass filter on a duplicated layer and change the blend mode to overlay.

[image]

Comment: You might want to add that the image is gray because its offset to avoid negative values. And overlay is basically add anything above 128 and subtract values below. So unsharpmask is basically boost high frequencies filter. I am adding an answer to this effect but would prefer to delete it in favor of your answer. Also there is still a 3rd usecase which is frequency separation.

Comment: Minor quibble: 1st sentence: "Filters out" means "eliminates," so a low-pass filter (blur) does not "filter out the low frequencies." High-pass filter (allows high frequencies to pass through it);low-pass filter (allows low frequencies to pass through it). A low-pass filter is also called a "high-cut filter" since it eliminates high frequencies. And so it goes for a high-pass being a low-cut.

Comment: joojaa- good comment. Yorik - thank you, fixed it.

Comment: Holy crap. Take an image into a Photoshop file. Duplicate the layer with the image in it. Blur (value 10) on layer 1. High pass filter (value 10) on layer 2. Set layer 2 to 50% opacity. Add a contrast layer, set it to legacy and +50 contrast. Compare that to the original image. Mind blown. That perfectly explains what it all does.

Comment: @DirkvB I tried what you said and it worked. Could you explain the reasoning behind 50% opacity and +50 contrast? Also to note, this method closely recreates the original image, but it is not identical (just run a difference blend between original and this one to see what I mean).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference blend thing. That's awesome! I think, on a high level, it's about adding two images to eachother by taking halves of each. You lose data from both, so that "flattens" the ranges. "Ranges" refers to the pixel's colour values. I'm no specialist (math isn't my strong suit) so I can only explain how it made sense to me :) If you happen to find a better answer, do share!

Answer (score 7):

A high pass filter is a fitter that removes low frequency information form a singnal. Now there are many ways to implement a high pass filter, but photoshops high pass filter most likely is the result by subtracting the blurred image from the original (as mentioned by [@filip](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/89981/18306)). Simply all of image minus the low frequency is just the high frequency.

Now if you subtract a blur from a image you will end up with pixels that are negative. This is not possible for photoshop. So what is instead done is the result is offset by 127 (or 0.5 if you want to floating point values) so gray actually means no value change. The overlay and linear light mode are designed to operate in reverse of images encoded this way (bit depending on what you need piece wise multiplication/addition or addition/subtraction).

Now what would you use this for? Well it can get used to isolate edges, and the primary use case is to use it as a sharpening tool. In fact unsharp mask does this in one step. Sometimes, however, unsharp mask  does not give you enough control of the results. So you might use the high pass filter to split out the intermediate stage and manipulate it to control where you want the sharpening to happen and where not.

This brings us to [frequency separation](https://fstoppers.com/post-production/ultimate-guide-frequency-separation-technique-8699) workflows, see it might be that your image is slightly unevenly light or quite often the skin is somewhat uneven. But you don't exactly want to destroy the texture of the image. So now you split your image into low and high components. You can then paint the low components to a moire uniform color, while retaining the texture layer on top. Or you can do the reverse eliminate flaws in the high frequency map while retaining the overall look and feel. For accuracy reasons you'd most likely not use both blur an high pass, instead you'd subtract manually, but this is still the same method just blurs and rounding of results differ.

[image: Example]

**Image 1**: Frequency separation makes it easy to fix old shoes, admittedly i should have done a bit more work. Original image from [here](https://pixabay.com/en/old-shoe-brown-shoe-shoe-961651/).

Now there is a LOT of magic that you can do with this filter. But unfortunately many of these magic workflows may require you to think like a signal processing guru. For example high pass filtering may work as a basis for a noise reduction algorithm or as a rectifying layer for image lightness masked haze removal etc.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers so far have touched on the maths behind the filter.  [Here's a detailed writeup](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/freqfilt.htm) from which I quote:

> Frequency filters process an image in the frequency domain. The image is Fourier transformed, multiplied with the filter function and then re-transformed into the spatial domain. Attenuating high frequencies results in a smoother image in the spatial domain, attenuating low frequencies enhances the edges.

At this point we should note that a high-pass filter passes high frequencies and *attenuates (i.e. reduces) low frequencies*.

> As a result of attenuating (or blocking) the low frequencies, areas of constant intensity in the input image are zero in the output of the highpass filter. Areas of a strong intensity gradient, containing the high frequencies, have positive and negative intensity values in the filter output. In order to display the image on the screen, an offset is added to the output in the spatial domain and the image intensities are scaled. This results in a middle grayvalue for low frequency areas and dark and light values for the edges.

(This quote is from about halfway through, and precedes an example image that should be quite helpful).

The article I've linked is well worth a read, and has some quite clear examples (click on the images).  It's too long to summarise and relies on the figures included in it.

Comment: and just for the layman's sake: *attenuate* means "reduce the force, value or impact"

Comment: @Yorik that didn't occur to me. It's a word I use daily in my work. Edited

Comment: @ChrisH Fourier transform is one way to implement a high pass filter (not the only on though) but i am pretty sure form past experimentation that Photoshop does not do a  a Fourier directly but rather subtracts a blur instead. However, It might be that newer photoshops actually use Fourier for the blur (pre CS, CC versions did not apparently do this) since it offers a shortcut for computing the blur.... But FFT has its share of problems and might be that PS is actually just splatting a convolution kernel without this optimization in the loop. So i fact filip did explain how the filter is done.

Comment: @joojaa subtracting a blur is what unsharp mask does though, and both options exist so I have my doubts. If I had photoshop I'd try to test (though as the shape of the filter in the Fourier domain is unknown if would be hard to prove decisively what's used). Anything I could test in the gimp wouldn't help much.

Comment: @ChrisH well, you get both out of the same operation and codebase. Only higpass was more useful in the past when you couldn't do nondestructive edits. But the operations yeild exactly the same results or at least they dealt the same results last time i tested doing this about 1.5 years ago. Likewise you could do unsharp mask with a fourier or any of the other frequency domain related transforms. They are mathematically equivalent, though they may have different border constraints in discrete solutions.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a convolution kernel not an FT. See for example the "custom" filter, which lets you define the kernel directly. All the other filters just build the kernels for you with some human-friendly parameters.

Comment: @OrangeDog I can't rule it out but just becasue some filters definitely use a convolution kernel doesn't mean all do. Convolution-based high-pass filters can be prone to noise but I see that there are some enhancements to be made there

Comment: @ChrisH and Fourier transforms on discrete data are also prone to noise.

Comment: @OrangeDog they are indeed; I use them all the time.  Which approach is worse for noise probably depends on the nature of the noise and the signal

Comment: Certainly for large images on computers, a convolution is also a lot quicker than an FT process. It's only a single pass of the image and can sometimes be done in-place without having to allocate another copy of the buffer.

Comment: @OrangeDog that's certainly true.

Answer (score 0):

High Pass is a sharpening filter. You could say it's a mix of "detect edges" and "sharpening". 
Sharpening detect sudden changes between pixels brightness or color and then change them. So bright parts are brighter and dark one are darker.

But the High Pass task is to notice just the edges. The radius setting tells the filter how many pixels around detected edge should be included in the filtered image (layer).

Now, this filter is not designed to be used on itself (that's why, I think, it's in different catalog), you should use the filtered image with the base one, using blend modes or similar, to pop up the edges on picture. That's why the "not included" part of picture are neutral gray. So they won't affects colors when in blend mode.